# Why does the obj variable have to be defined inside the for loop vs outside?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

If I define the obj variable inside the outer `for` loop, it doesn't overwrite the first iterations data, but when I define the obj variable outside the `for` loop, it overwrites the first iterations data with the second iterations data. Can someone please help me understand why?

Also, i'm aware there's other ways to answer this problem with map() and reduce(), but i have to solve it this way.

```
function transformEmployeeData(arr) {
let newArr = []
**let obj = {}**
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    **let obj = {}**
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        obj[arr[i][j][0]] = arr[i][j][1]
    }
    newArr.push(obj)
}
    return newArr
}
```

---

```
var input = [
[
    ['firstName', 'Joe'],
    ['lastName', 'Blow'],
    ['age', 42],
    ['role', 'clerk']
],
[
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['role', 'manager']
]
];

console.log(transformEmployeeData(input))
```

Comment: The variable declaration doesn't matter, but you need to create a new object (`= {}`) on every iteration. `push` does not copy the contents of the object into the array. If you don't re-initialise the object, all array indices refer to the *same* object instance.

Answer (score 0):

**Objects are references.**

```js
var objectCollection = [];
var o = {}

o.foo = 1;
objectCollection.push(o);

o.foo = 2;
objectCollection.push(o);


console.log(objectCollection)    //All 2 elemets are the same object

objectCollection[0].foo = 100;
console.log(objectCollection);
```

What would you expect in the above array? Each element referes to the same object - and if that object changes, everywhere that object is referred to - also will be changed.

**Let's go back to your question**

When you declare your object outside both the loops, what you push to the array is that same object every time. If you declare it just inside the outer loop, a new object is created for the inner loop to process every time.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on here. The biggest issue is that you push `obj` onto `newArr` and if you only declare `obj` once, then it's just a reference to that object that is pushed. So when you push it a second time, you have **2 references** to the **one object**.

For the same reason, when your values get changed to for the second entry in the input, it overwrites the values in `obj` with Mary Jenkins' data but that changes in the **one object** and hence changes in both `newArr[0]` and `newArr[1]` since they both point to the same object.

By declaring `obj` inside of the loop you will be pushing **2 distinct objects** onto the `newArr` array and get what you want.